# WSO2 IS 5.7.0 - Password Minimum Age configuration in Minutes

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there any options/configurations available in WSO2 Identity Server to configure password minimum age in minutes?

As part of our requirement we need to configure password minimum age in minutes, so we have verified the WSO2 IS document and we did not found any configuration to fix the problem.

Version - WSO2 IS 5.7.0

Answer (score 0):

The default authenticator only supports 'in days'. But as this is an extension, you can just customize this default authenticaor's code re-build the artifact.

[Git](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-passwordPolicy/blob/v1.0.17/component/authenticator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/policy/password/PasswordChangeHandler.java)